# nmcli bridge refuses to come up

Tags: bridge, libvirt, nmcli

I tried running the commands found [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-8-add-network-bridge-br0-with-nmcli-command/)
But my bridge refuses to come up. Stuck in `DOWN`.

- the slave-bridge interface is ethernet. No wifi on this host.
- Tried using ip link to bring the interface up
- `ip -br a` shows the bridge has and IP address as I need it to.
- nothing works the bridge refuses to come up no matter what.
- tried `systemctl restart NetworkManager.service` did not work.
- tried everything [here](http://blog.leifmadsen.com/blog/2016/12/01/create-network-bridge-with-nmcli-for-libvirt/) too.
- Tried removing the nmcli configuration on `eno2` (The slave interface), and turning the interface up. Still nothing.

Everything I read states "Just turn down the other interface" but thats not working. The other interface is using the same IP address, but its down, does that matter?

Why is the bridge stuck in `DOWN` state?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.
I was using the incorrect ifname for my slave-bridge. Here are the actual commands I used (eno2 is the actual interface).

Firs things first remove any configurations for the interface you are going to use. You will ideally want to do all this via console:

```
# nmcli con eno2 up
# nmcli con delete eno2
# nmcli con add type bridge autoconnect yes ifname br-mgmt con-name br-mgmt ipv4.addresses '10.10.10.10/24' ipv4.gateway '10.10.10.1' ipv4.dns '10.10.10.53,10.10.10.54' ipv4.dns-search 'my.domain.internal' ipv4.method manual
# nmcli con add type bridge-slave autoconnect yes con-name br-slave-eno2 ifname eno2 master br-mgmt
# nmcli con show

NAME              UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE
br-mgmt           39a06773-dbd7-4ab5-ad08-40266c14180c  bridge    br-mgmt
virbr0            f6769db1-0e52-4f8f-822e-1f511c31519f  bridge    virbr0
br-slave-eno2     e63b0757-a725-4916-9f37-e4dd2cda2e39  ethernet  eno2
```

At this point MAKE sure your bridge and slave interface are both green. If they are not they are not active and will not work. IF they are up continue:

```
nmcli con up br-mgmt
```

Now the bridge interface comes up and you should be able to ping.